# How can i get both OnClick and OnTouch Listeners for an ImageButton?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am trying to build a audio recording app. When I hold my imagebutton, it start to record my voice and when I release the button the file is stored in my phone. But when I do not hold the button, just click the imagebutton then the app closed. I want that if I accidentally pressed the button then it showed me a toast. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton recordButton;
    String pathSave = "";
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!checkPermissionFromDevice())
            requestPermission();
            recordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
            recordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if(checkPermissionFromDevice()){
                            String folder_main = "AudioRecord";

                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
                            if (!f.exists()) {
                                f.mkdirs();
                            }
                            pathSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/AudioRecord/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.wav";
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pathSave,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            setupMediaRecorder();
                            try {
                                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                                mediaRecorder.start();
                            } catch (IOException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Recording Started...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            textView.setText("Recording Started...");
                            //textView.setText(pathSave);
                        } else{
                            requestPermission();
                        }
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        doFileUpload();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Recording Finished...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the permissions in the manifest file? And have they been granted by the app? It would be useful if you show the exception.

Comment: Yes I set the permission in the manifest file and they are granted by app. My voice are recorded when I hold the button. But when i click the button instead of hold it show me this error. Process: com.example.audiorecordingpractice, PID: 18206
    java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_stop(Native Method)

Comment: Maybe this is caused, because the `mediarecorder` could not be initialized by the time the button is released and `ACTION_UP` is triggered. You could use a boolean flag `started = true` after you start mediarecorder. And in the `ACTION_UP` event you can check whether the `started` value is true and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

> Android docs on MediaRecorder.stop()
>
> public void stop ()

Stops recording. Call this after start(). Once recording is stopped, you will have to configure it again as if it has just been constructed. **Note that a RuntimeException is intentionally thrown to the application, if no valid audio/video data has been received when stop() is called. This happens if stop() is called immediately after start()**. The failure lets the application take action accordingly to clean up the output file (delete the output file, for instance), since the output file is not properly constructed when this happens.

Throws
IllegalStateException   if it is called before start().

You need to catch this Exception while calling                                                       `mediaRecorder.stop();`